# Search Core Result Webpart-Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have studied sharepoint development i now i'm doing the last part of my education to get the exam which is practicing in real life and that is what i do nowadays. I'm developing a sharepoint intranet for the company i'm practicing in and i'm facing the following topic--->
How can i filter out unwanted search results so that i only get documents in the results and no links/urls?
Thnx in advance =)

Comment: The solution to this topic is to do the following:
Central Administration ---> Manage Service Applications ---> Search Searvice Application.

Look at Quick Launch then find the Queries and Results. Click on Scopes and Chooes the one you use in your search! For example my default search scope is All Sites. Click on the scope and you will see that you are able to add own rules to make it bahave differently! The needed rule in this case is to add the following rule:

in Scope Type Rule choose Proprety Query
in Add Property Restrictions choose IsDocument
in Behavior choose Require.
Update & Crawl.

Comment: Forgot to note that first i hade to make IsDocument available to use in the scopes as i went to Metadata Properties under Queries and Results ---> finded IsDocument under the Managed Properties, clicked on it and checked the box which makes is available in search scopes. And lastly when you add the IsDocument rule to this scope make it equal to 1 as it is of boolean type.